# Windows: how a logged remote user can disconnect its own connection of a remote sharing folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-10, windows-8

Consider there are some machines connected in the same LAN, for simplicity assume thus the following:

```
Beta PC //referred later how server side
  localUserBeta
  RemoteUserTypeA
  RemoteUserTypeB

Alpha PC// referred later how the client side [remote user]
  localUserAlpha
```

Alpha is able to connect and access a shared folder of Beta through the `RemoteUserTypeA` user, how is possible to disconnect (from the **client** side) and re connect again but with `RemoteUserTypeB` user?.

I followed the following link

- [How to Disconnect Users From a Shared Folder or Drive](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-disconnect-user-or-users-from-a-shared-folder-or-dri/)

Two Problems:

- It is must be done from the **server** side.
- Even when works, it works really partially: the server is able to close the session of the client, but the client with just doing click in other directory (to enter) within the shared folder, is able to re establish *automatically* the connection.

Until this point I expected to see again the login window asking for the username/password

Therefore I need a way where Alpha (client side) to disconnect to the shared folder and re connect using other user of the Beta (server side)

The clients can be: Windows 7/8/10. Currently the unique way to change the user about the client side is shutdown the PC from the client side itself. It of course is not very viable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking on the disconntected drive, use the `Map network drive` dialog, and select **Connect using different credentials**

[image: Connect using different credentials]